# Internal state of std::discrete_distribution and random numbers quality

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I am iteratively generating random numbers via `std::discrete_distribution`. Does the quality of random numbers degrade if after each iteration I reset the internal state of the distribution (which is equivalent to creating `std::discrete_distribution` object inside the loop):

```
// inputs:
//   int n_samples
//   int n_energies
//   double energies[n_energies]

std::mt19937_64 generator;

for (int i = 0; i < n_samples; ++i ) {
    std::discrete_distribution<int> d(energies, energies + n_energies);

    int index = d(generator);

    // DO SMTH WITH INDEX
    // energies array may change between iterations here.
}
```

The reason I am asking is that `energies` may change between iterations (depending on the algorithm flow, which is not predictable).

In one border case, they change every iteration so above code is ok, since there is nothing I can do here.

In the other border case, they do not change between iterations at all. Which is equivalent to resetting internal state of `std::discrete_distribution` while probabilities are the same.

In the latter case, is the quality of generated random numbers inferior to the quality when distribution state is not reset (i.e., `std::discrete_distribution` object is created outside the loop)?

Comment: The quality of values produced by `discrete_distribution` depends on the quality of U(0,1)'s provided by `generator`. If you're changing the parameterization of `discrete_distribution` but keeping the same `generator`, the latter should keep producing a sequence of U(0,1)'s that pass statistical tests for independence and uniformity, so you should be okay. It might be expensive to keep instantiating new instances of `discrete_distribution`, but you could sidestep that to the maximum extent possible by making the instantiation conditional on whether `energies` has changed.

Comment: In other words: `discrete_distribution` doesn't itself contain any non-deterministic internal state. It just performs simple, deterministic math to turn a uniform `[0, 1]` distribution into discrete distribution. All the interesting stuff that can affect quality is in `generator`.

Comment: Tnx, pjs and Igor.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik What do you mean by "non-determenistic" state? It can contain *some* state.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I mean that every instance of `discrete_distribution` initialized with the same set of weights will produce the same output given the same input sequence from the generator. The OP is concerned that the past history of a particular `discrete_distribution` instance might influence its future output; that the instance on which `operator()` was already called previously might behave differently than a freshly constructed instance with the same weights. I do not believe this is the case.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I think the standard theoretically allows additional internal state (otherwise why `reset()` exists), but in practice it seems you're right, at least in the big 3 standard libs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very existence of `.reset()` implies that the distribution could have additional internal state (so resetting could theoretically affect the output quality).

But I've checked the big three standard libraries ([libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/libstdc++/api/a00497_source.html#l05532), [libc++](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/ab1a7f1057e61e6166d92690a829938508620647/libcxx/include/__random/discrete_distribution.h#L111), [MSVC STL](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/46843b3bf320c6070ff63e978936bcf898e5a2bc/stl/inc/random#L2896)), and in all of them `std::discrete_distribution::reset()` is a no-op. (And same for `std::uniform_{int,real}_distribution`.)